# MySQL Optimization And Indexing

Tags: mysql

Hi Guys please advice me with this one.

I have a tablemasterlist with million of records . 
I used Index for CycleDate and ProductType .
I was expecting record count of 100,132 but the sql scan
too many rows .

```
explain SELECT * FROM tblmasterlist where  CycleDate BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND '2014-08-30'
```

[image]

---

Comment: what if you use the old school method of cycledate >= 2014-08-01 and cycledate <= 2014-08-30

Comment: Is your index of a type btree?

Comment: Try to run ANALYZE TABLE; is MRR on on the server? You can check `select  @@optimizer_switch;`

Comment: It will also be helpful if you can show create table I would like to review your indexes

Comment: tnx @Mike about this idea cycledate >= 2014-08-01 and cycledate <= 2014-08-30 but i already try this one but no luck i also try to use multiple index but also no luck .

Comment: I have no idea about the MRR i will read about this first and i will back to you anyway thanks for helping guys .

Answer (score 1):

Your index on `CycleDate` is ok and used in this query. Like Mike stated, make sure it is a `Typ=BTREE` since you select on a RANGE of values (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html)).

The number of records given by `EXPLAIN` is an estimate of the number of rows not the real amount MySQL has to scan (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-output-columns)):

```
The rows column indicates the number of rows MySQL believes 
it must examine to execute the query. 
For InnoDB tables, this number is an estimate, and may not always be exact.
```

You can increase the accurancy by updating the index statistic:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE tblmasterlist
```